# sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''

Tags: linux, shell, sed, scripting

I have already read a similar question, but there is no solution to my problem.

I want to delete some line in some file I use sed in the script this is the code.

```
line="this"
del='echo "'/"$line"/d'"' #it's a AltGr+7 on AZERTY keyboard but for readability of the code I use '
sed -i $del /home/example/fic.txt
```

I also try:

```
line="this"
del='echo "/"$line"/d"'
sed $del /home/example/fic > /home/example/fic
```

but I have the same error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
line="this"
del=`echo "/"$line"/d"`
sed $del /home/example/fic > /home/example/fic
```

In your code, you are single quotes while assigning value to variable `del`. which will consider as a static string rather than executing it. We can use backticks or `$()` to execute it.

better way,

```
line="this"
sed -i "/$line/d" /home/example/fic
```

- `-i` edit in line.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already note in the comment, I don't know how to add ` in the code and I use ' only for example. I use ` in my script but it doesn't work :)

Comment: it' s work when I use directly sed "/$line/d" /home/example/fic Thank you :)

Comment: Now when I call the scrit which contente sed -i "/$line/d" /home/example/fic  I Have this error: sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression

Comment: thank you it's OK know :)

Comment: hope u have not declared `line`

Comment: Use `$(...)` instead of  backticks -- easier to see that it's different from single quote.